# Como ver a quantidade de resultados com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Boa noite,

Como uso, faço para contar a quantidade de resultados de um select no banco de dados usando PDO?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-  requested-with');

include_once("conPDO.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$email = $data->email;
$senha = $data->senha;

$login=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email=:email AND senha=:senha");
$login->bindValue("email", $email);
$login->bindValue("senha", $senha);
$login->execute();

$count = $login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
print_r($count);
```

Comment: tenta $nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from blah')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $nRows;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos jeitos que eu utilizaria pra fazer essa contagem sem afetar os registros seria com o FETCH_ASSOC.

Tenta fazer assim, ao invés de FETCH_NUM use `$login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` e atribua para `$result`. Depois faça `count($result)` e você terá o número de elementos no array de retorno. Que equivale ao número de linhas. Dessa forma você pode pegar o número total sem mexer na quantidade de registros ou no modelo que você está retornando.

Comment: Só count($result)? Não ta faltando nada nessa parte?

Comment: Não, ficaria algo do tipo `if(count($result) > 0) { ..... }`

Comment: Lembrando que você vai atribuir o valor do login para o `$result`, como em `$result = $login->fetch(....)`

Comment: Qualquer coisa você pode se referir ao manual do count também http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php